# Firebase AUTH API to signInWithPhoneNumber is resulting in a 400 bad request

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using the basic firebase starter kit out on github to test out the firebase authentication piece. Below is the firebase starter kit link which walks through the steps to setup firebase with a basic react native application.

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter

The App.js has been replaced to have a very simple form that takes phone number as input and invokes the firebase auth API signInWithPhoneNumber() to send out a text message. Below is the relevant code

**Firebase intilization with all the relevant config details**

```
firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: '',
authDomain: '<>',
databaseURL: '<>',
projectId: '<>',
storageBucket: '<>',
messagingSenderId: '<>'
});
```

**Auth API call**

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
.then(confirmResult => console.log(confirmResult))
.catch(error => this.setState({message: Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}}));
```

This above API call(2) is resulting in a 400 bad request. A snapshot of the logs seen in the catlog is as below

```
05-07 14:04:21.643 3509 6366 W FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] PhoneVerificationSession constructor
05-07 14:04:21.648 3509 4952 W FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
05-07 14:04:22.284 3509 13712 E Volley : [237] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=
05-07 14:04:22.286 3509 6366 W FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onFailure
05-07 14:04:22.451 3509 4952 W FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
```

Not sure what the reason for the 400 bad request is. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Please let me know if any more information is needed to understand the issue.

Answer (score -1):

PhoneAuth method from React-Native-Firebase use the native Firebase SDK for iOS or Android, and in the case of iOS is  only supported if you have enabled pushnotifications. i think for android must be the same. but on iOS you have to join to developer program and it cost 100 USD i think. PhoneAuth method in JavaScript SDK is not supported on React-Native.

if you already joined to Apple developers Program, be sure you have all certificates for pushnotifications on your App. the are many tutorials on Youtube.
if you want, try to catch the error and post it here. i would also try to post the error on github.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am working for the android platform as of now and the push notifications are enabled. How to get a more detailed error ?

Comment: try to print in console the error. and the error.message. then go to inspect in dev tools, and post here what it says.